# jQuery - when btn is clicked on form with empty fields, the background color and text fade in

Tags: jquery, css

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJcAL/2/)

CSS

```
    .fade-in{
  background-color: #ff9696;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
  transition: background 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
}

.alertError{
  background-color: #ff9696;
  color: red;
  padding: 15px 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.box-button').click(function() {
    $('.alertError').fadeIn('slow', function() {
       $(".alertError").addClass('fade-in');
   });
  });
```

HTML

```
    <div class ="alertError">missing fields</div>
<button class="box-button">
                example
 </button>
```

trying for ages to fade in background color and error text when form button is submitted with empty fields. But no to avail. I have feeling that css or jquery might not be right or working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/348Fv/)</kbd>

Just change the position of css classes

```
.alertError { /* Move this class first */
    background-color: #ff9696;
    color: red;
    padding: 15px 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade-in {
    background-color: #ff9696;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    transition: background 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Problem**

`opacity` property is overridden by `alertError` class

Comment: Or better yet, change `.fade-in` to `.alertError.fade-in`

Comment: @haim770 yes it's good option but we are not sure OP is using it only once or maybe with many other classes .

Comment: @TusharGupta - thanks but in your fiddle, background color pop out not fade in?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `opacity` from *fade-in* and *alertError* class and use `display:none;` for *alertError*

Use

```
.fade-in {
    background-color: #ff9696;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
    transition: background 0.5s linear;     
}
.alertError {
    background-color: #ff9696;
    color: red;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display:none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpLaB/)

Comment: ah so need to set display:none so it will not show anything till click button? thanks

Comment: thanks, I am sorry but the problem is that my error messages will be done via grails dynamically. so If I follow your example using display: none, then try click button, it will not show fade in or any text.

Answer (score 0):

Try with using like this.  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KJcAL/4/)

CSS

```
.alertError{

  background-color: #ff9696;
  color: red;
  padding: 15px 0;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
     -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
      -ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
       -o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
          transition: background 0.5s linear;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var err_message = "missing fields";
    $('.box-button').on('click',function() {
        $('div').attr('class','alertError').html(err_message);
    });
});
```

Html

```
  <div></div>
  <button class="box-button">example</button>
```

Comment: how come I have to use <div></div>? as it is templated dynamically it will probably need to find which div to add in alertError class.